# Unable to resolve "../../App" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js" Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: javascript, expo, vue-native

I cant open my vue file with expo. It gives AppEntry.js error. The problem is in AppEntry.js file my vue file hasnt seen so it gives error. I couldnt find how to add .vue extension. I need help guys this error drives me mad.

I updated my expo-cli and vue-native-cli and I use node 10.6.1 version.

### node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import { activateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';


import App from "../../App" // The problem part is here. AppEntry doesnt accept .vue file I cant even see it. 

if (__DEV__
) 
{
  activateKeepAwake();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

---

Also in same place

### node_modules/expo/package.json

```
 "sideEffects": 
[

    "*.fx.js",

    "*.fx.web.js"
  ],
```

I tried to add .vue here and it didnt work for me. If you ask me to solve this we must add a code which provides AppEntry.js to read .vue extensions.

I expect see the App.vue page but I take AppEntry.js error.

Comment: I also have this problem. It is my first vue-native application and this is not a good start, hopefully someone can tell us what is happening

Comment: I have the same issue and I also started to use expo for the first time, this is weird, too much magic.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and I fixed it by installing 'expo-keep-awake' and 'react-native-unimodules' by using 'npm install react-native-unimodules' and 'npm install expo-keep-awake'.

According to [this page](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-keep-awake), you should ensure that react-native-unimodules is installed when using the expo-keep-awake.

Hope this is helpful to you :)

Comment: is `--save-dev` required?

Comment: For me, I was able to solve it without '--save-dev'.